# Simples menu de configurações com CheckBoxPreference Android

Tags: java, android, menu

Tenho um simples menu de configurações onde possuo um `CheckBoxPreference`. Quero definir modo de silêncio quando o checkBox estiver marcado e modo normal quando ele não estiver marcado. O código do som eu já tenho, mas estou com problemas para pegar o valor do checkBoxPreference,já que só tenho a classe de configurações que extende `PreferenceActivity`. Segue o código abaixo:

Prefs.java

```
package br.com.pedro.menu;

import br.com.pedro.school.R;

import android.content.Context;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
    AudioManager som;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    // USE AudioManager for Settingringing from vibration
    som = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

}
```

}

xml/prefs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/geral" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="silenciar"
        android:summary="@string/mudo_inst"
        android:title="@string/mudo" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

por favor me ajudem!

Answer (score 1):

Altere Prefs.java de forma a registar um `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

```
package br.com.pedro.menu;

import br.com.pedro.school.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
    AudioManager som;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);    

} 

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    //Teste pelo valor que foi alterado e actue em conformidade
    if(preference.getKey().equals("silenciar"){

        if((boolean) newValue){
            //ligar som
        }
        else
        {
            //desligar som
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Se você quiser apenas testar o `CheckBox` deverá registar um `OnPreferenceChangeListener`

```
Preference ckboxPref = this.findPreference("silenciar");
ckboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //Testar o novo valor
        if((boolean) newValue){
            //ligar som
        }
        else
        {
            //desligar som
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Na sequência do seu comentário vou tentar explicar o que se passa.

Sempre que você alterar o valor do `CheckBox` o método `onPreferenceChange` é chamado. Aí, de acordo com o valor do `CheckBox`, você liga ou desliga o som. Como o método retorna `true` o valor é guardado.

Penso que ou seu problema é quando a sua aplicação arranca.
Você terá de fazer o mesmo teste na `MainActivity` da sua aplicação.

No `onCreate` você tem de testar o valor do `CheckBox`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .......
    .......
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean silenciar = preferences.getBoolean("silenciar", false);
    if(silenciar){
        //desligar som
    }
    else
    {
        //ligar som
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu poderia Testar o checkbox e salvá-lo ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: O que é que você quer dizer com salvá-lo?

Comment: Usar da classe `SharedPreferences` para quando o usuário encerrar a aplicação e retornar, o CheckBoxPreference esteja marcado da forma com que ele setou anteriormente!